# Can I debug a Grails application with a Text Editor such as Sublime Text 2?

Tags: debugging, grails, groovy, sublimetext

I am getting started with Grails and I watched quite a few videos where the presenters demonstrated Grails 2.X with the command line and a text editor such as textmate.

Here are my 2 questions:

1. Is it the recommended workflow or most popular one? Or most people use STS?
2. I enjoy text editors and I would like to know if it is possible to debug a Grails app with Sublime Text 2

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean interactive debugging? I use sublime text 2, but it doesn't do interactive debugging

Comment: I'd like to watch the videos. Please, add a link

Comment: Hi, yes I meant interactive debugging. @ArturoHerrero, I haven't seen videos on debugging with a text editor but I have seen several videos where the presenter would use VIM or Textmate such as [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHUPLOnUF4g) or at [link](http://www.bobbywarner.com/). Once I get a good grasp of the debudding, I hope I will do a short post or a screencast.

Comment: I find the closed as not constructive too strict, this is a constructive question and the answer is very useful

Comment: Seconding previous comment : Definitely a constructive and helpful question

Comment: Text editor + interactive debugger = IDE, therefore you want to use something like Eclipse, NetBeans, or IntelliJ Idea. I personally use ST2 and a terminal to run grails, with the occasional (very occasional) `grails -debug` and `jdb -attach`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can debug grails applications outside of an IDE with the bare bones `jdb` debugger that comes with the JDK.  You won't get the typical IDE debugging experience, but something more like a traditional command-line debugger like `gdb` on Unix.

To get started, run your application with `grails -debug` instead of `grails`.  You'll see

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

At this point, run `jdb` as follows:

```
jdb -attach localhost:5005
```

You should be prompted with a prompt like `main[1]`.  Now you can set breakpoints and watches and start your app.  For example:

```
main[1] stop in mypackage.MyController.action()
Deferring breakpoint mypackage.MyController.action().
It will be set after the class is loaded.
main[1] run
```

When the breakpoint is hit, you can step through the code with `step` and `next`, and continue running with `cont`.

Comment: Thank you. On windows, this is the command I need to type to get it working: jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=localhost,port=5005