# Running Groovysh in Grails Application does not accept input

Tags: grails, groovy, read-eval-print-loop, groovyshell

I'm trying to find a [Pry Deubgger](http://www.alanmacdougall.com/blog/2012/06/08/interactive-debugging-with-pry/) equivalent on Groovy.

I found a good enough project named [groovy-debugger](http://aaronbabcock.blogspot.ro/2011/11/groovy-debugging.html) and updated it's dependencies to run against groovy 2.3.1 which comes with Grails 2.4.0.

If I open a groovysh just a blinking cursor will be shown which does not accept any input.

I tried to get the input stream and output stream of a current grails console, but it does not help.

Anyone can help me setup my beloved [REPL-driven development](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9j_Mf91M0I) environment on Groovy.

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285696/can-i-debug-a-grails-application-with-a-text-editor-such-as-sublime-text-2

Comment: To voters for closing the question: It's not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for a drop in REPL, please do not vote for close if you don't understand the question exactly!

Answer (score 1):

So using Grails 2.4.0 I created a new project and started the shell with `grails shell` and it was able to accept input with no problem. This is with Mac OS X. What operating system are you running?

Comment: I've used the `com.gdb.GdbShell.gdb()` successfully on my Mac at home even though I put the command in a `.template` file to inspect the variables while generating code through `scaffold` plugin but I don't know if it works on Linux(Ubuntu 14.4) or not.

What I'm trying to do now, is to pause a RUNNING Grails application with an open console to inspect variables, and run arbitrary code.

Please take a look at http://aaronbabcock.blogspot.ro/2011/11/groovy-debugging.html